# Angular error this.method is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm creating a login application from scratch. Everything works fine except one situation where I try to login then logout out and after I try to login again I get this 
**error:**

```
LoginFormComponent.html:23 ERROR TypeError: this.authService.authenticateUser is not a function
    at LoginFormComponent.onLoginSubmit (login-form.component.ts:50)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginFormComponent.html:23)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
    at eval (core.js:10587)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
```

Here is the code from 2 files. First is `Auth.service`. A user service that is injected in `login-form.component.js` which is the second file where I communicate with backend server.

**auth.service.js**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  registerUser(user) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
  authenticateUser(user) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
  getProfile() {
      const headers = new Headers();
      this.loadToken();
      headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authenticateUser = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }
  logout() {
    this.authenticateUser = null;
    this.user  = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }
}
```

**login-form.component.js**

```
import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormGroupDirective, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.scss']
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
  showError: boolean;
  error: String;
  loginForm: any;
  // authService: AuthService;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private authService: AuthService) {
    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(30)]]
    });
  }

  trigger = false;
  isLoginPassed = false;
  @Output() public LoginEvent = new EventEmitter();

  closeLoginForm() {
    this.trigger = false;
    this.LoginEvent.emit(this.trigger);
  }
  openSnackBar(msg: String, color: String) {
    // open Box that shows if the account has been been logged in
    this.snackBar.open( msg.toString() , 'Close', {
      duration: 3000,
      panelClass: [color.toString()]
    });
  }
  onLoginSubmit() {
    const user = {
      username: this.loginForm.controls['username'].value,
      password: this.loginForm.controls['password'].value
    };
    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success) {
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.openSnackBar('You have been logged in', 'confirm');
        this.router.navigate(['main']);
        this.closeLoginForm();
      } else {
        this.loginForm.reset();
        this.openSnackBar(data.message, 'warning');
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

HTML where I'm calling the function `onLoginSubmit()`

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="!isLoginPassed">
  <div class="logInWindow">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Log In to BANDZ account </h1>
      <div class="x" (click)=closeLoginForm()></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Container">
      <form action="" method="post" [formGroup]="loginForm" class="form form-login">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>
            <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
            Username
          </mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Please provide your username" formControlName="username">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>
            <mat-icon>lock-outline</mat-icon>
            Password
          </mat-label>
          <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Please provide your password" formControlName="password">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" (click)="onLoginSubmit()" mat-raised-button>Log in</button>
        <a id="lostPassword" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
        <br>
        <a id="registerAccount" href="#">Don't have an account?</a>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think something is wrong with "binding" but don't know where to start. If you have any tips how to handle this problem I would appreciate this.

Comment: Hello Sajeetharan. I added html code where I'm calling the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are accidentally setting that function to `null` in your logout method.

```
logout() {
   this.authenticateUser = null;
    ...
}
```

Did you mean to set the `authToken` to `null` instead?

Comment: Oh yes of course my mistake. Really stupid mistake. The sad part is that the error still remains ...                  
 LoginFormComponent.html:23 ERROR TypeError: this.authService.authenticateUser is not a function
    at LoginFormComponent.onLoginSubmit (login-form.component.ts:49)

Comment: It happens AFTER  I login successfully  > logout and try to log in again

Comment: You are making a similar mistake in your `storeUserData` method as well...

Comment: I'm ashamed of myself don't know what I was thinking when I was writing this. Thank you Daniel for spotting this. It of course fixed the problem. I was just setting the function to null therefore the error.